# Highlight parts of a string if present in a list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to highlight parts of a Python string if the part is present in a list of 2-character words. When the 2-character words are spread apart, I am able to achieve what is needed, but I am not able to do it when the two words occur simultaneously in the string. Here is what I have so far:

```
r = ''
lofw = ['GO', 'IS', 'OD']
mystr1 = 'HISTORICAL'
pre = '<span style="color: red">'
post = '</span>'
for i in range(0, len(mystr1)-1):
    t = mystr1[i:i+2]
    if t in lofw:
        r = r[:-1] + pre + t + post            
    else:
        r = r[:-1] + t
```

This code works when there are no consecutive words from the list of words.

However, when there are consecutive words, it throws unwanted results. For example:

```
mystr2 = 'HISGODTORICAL'
```

Comment: Are you sure the first case works fine as well? When you find the "IS" and highlight it, you then loop over to "S" and add it again. Not sure that is what you want

Comment: Oh, yes! I have somehow missed it...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to use `str`'s [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method:

```py
lofw = ['GO','IS','OD']
mystr1 = 'HISTORICAL'

r = mystr1
pre = '<span style="color: red">'
post =  '</span>'
for sub in lofw:
    r = r.replace(sub, pre + sub + post)
```

For `HISTORICAL` this gives:

```
H<span style="color: red">IS</span>TORICAL
```

And for `HISGODTORICAL` this gives:

```
H<span style="color: red">IS</span><span style="color: red">GO</span>DTORICAL
```

---

If the immediate closing and opening of tags bothers you, you can add this after the loop:

```
r = r.replace(post+pre, "")
```

So now for `HISGODTORICAL` we will get:

```
H<span style="color: red">ISGO</span>DTORICAL
```

Comment: But in this case, it is not identifying OD

Comment: well a simple workaround will be to change the list to `lofw = ['GOD', 'GO','IS','OD']`